# Phase splitters/inverters using valves with directly-heated cathodes

Tags: audio, vacuum-tube, inverting-amplifier

I'm building an audio amplifier using [Raytheon 6418](http://tdsl.duncanamps.com/show.php?des=CK6418) valves and I'm struggling with the phase splitter.

The *6418* has a directly-heated cathode and I'm wondering what limitations this might introduce. Ideally I would use a [cathodyne](http://www.valvewizard.co.uk/cathodyne.html) design but, from what I understand, this might not be possible because there is no seperate cathode and thus no cathode resistor (R<sub>k</sub>).

For the same reason, I assume that [long-tailed pairs](http://www.valvewizard.co.uk/dcltp.html) cannot be used either. One solution I have come across is using a [paraphase inverter](http://www.valvewizard.co.uk/paraphase.html) ([schematic](http://www.valvewizard.co.uk/paraphase.html)), however I would ideally avoid this as it might introduce high levels of distortion.

- Am I correct in thinking that I cannot use a cathodyne/long-tailed pair?
- Is there a way of adjusting them to work with a directly-heated cathode?
- If not, then are there any other alternative designs that might be more suitable than a paraphase inverter?

Comment: Your second link requires a login.

Comment: Additionally, since vacuum tube designs are now a very niche area, please do elaborate on what a cathodyne or cathodyne/LTP is, and what Rₖ refers to. A schematic would be very helpful.

Comment: @Hearth apologies, I'm new to valve technology as well so shouldn't assume it's well-known! I've added some links to explain the terms I've used and removed the link that required a sign-in.

Comment: I'm curious why you're wanting to avoid introducing distortion. My understanding was that the main reason people still make tube amplifiers is specifically for that distortion.

Comment: @Hearth I'm doing this for a uni project where I'm creating a Hi-Fi amplifier from low-voltage tubes. Being that it is for Hi-Fi purposes, rather than for guitars, distortion isn't necessarily desirable in this case. Additionally, it is the _type_ of distortion that valves produce that people find desirable, namely the even-order harmonics introduced by overloading the valve. The distortion introduced here is undesirable in both cases. [See here](https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/tubes-valves/75414-paraphase-splitter-unpopular.html)

Comment: From its specs, this is essentially a hearing aid valve. Makes it an odd choice in a hi-fi amplifier.However, one approach that would work is transformer coupled output - a centre tapped secondary would give you phase splitting.

Comment: The point of the project is more the research and experimentation. It's obviously not a great choice of valve, the point is can it be done and how effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, a directly-heated cathode means that the heater power and the cathode signal share the same pins. But this does not preclude the circuit configurations you're considering, it just means that you need to decouple the signal from the heater power somehow.

This means that the heater power needs to "not care" about the signal voltage, and vice-versa. Since the heater power is going to be DC and your audio signal is AC, there is a number of ways that this can be approached.

If you want to use all passive components, you need a low-pass filter for the DC and a high-pass filter for the AC. However, if you want a relatively low cutoff frequency (presumably a few 10s or 100s of Hz), the components can get inconveniently large.

If you're willing to entertain the idea of additional active components — perhaps even transistors — you can control the heater power by means of a current source. This will have an inherently large effective source impedance, which will allow the signal voltage to be tapped off with no interference.

The filament only requires 10 mA @ 1.25 V, so either approach is reasonably feasible.

Comment: The traditional way of driving tubes like this was to use a separate battery to power the filaments, right? Of course that's not going to work if you want to not have to change batteries.

Comment: @Hearth: Sure, but that would require a separate battery (or isolated DC-DC converter) for each tube. I suspect that the applications for which these tubes were originally designed only needed the one tube.

Comment: @DaveTweed From what pin would I tap the non-inverting output signal? The filament input (3) or output (5)?

Comment: Even if you used separate transformers to heat filaments, the transformers provide noise injection path from the mains, and a feedback/interaction path among all the tubes via secondary-primary winding capacitance in each transformer.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the idea for the final amp is to have it run from a bunch of 9V batteries so mains noise won't be an issue

Comment: You can take the signal from either pin, or a combination of the two. If you've done your job right, they are functionally identical with respect to the signal.

Comment: @DaveTweed Which is why I said that's not really going to work here.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way it was done in old times is using a unity gain amplifier. Then one tube is driven directly from the voltage amplifier and another from the unity gain amplifier.
Hope it helps.